# store multiple values inside cookie using pure js

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to store multiple values (`integer`, `boolean`) inside cookie where I want to use `;` as a delimiter;

```
    function setCookie(name, downloaded, dontAskAgain, days) { 
        deleteCookie(name);
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
        }
        else var expires = "";
        var cdata = downloaded + delimiter + dontAskAgain;
        document.cookie = name +="=" + cdata + ";" + expires + "; path=/";         
    }
    function deleteCookie(name) {
        document.cookie = [name, '=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.', window.location.host.toString()].join('');
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong here, cause new value

```
setCookie("MyCookie", 0, false, 31)
```

is not set.
Is there a better way to do this with js only (not jquery lib.)?

Answer (score 0):

Browsers use the semicolon for native cookie delimitation, and you're cookie is confusing it.

try:

```
document.cookie = [name, encodeURIComponent('=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.'), window.location.host.toString()].join('');

    //or

document.cookie =  encodeURIComponent([name,'=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.', window.location.host.toString()].join(''));
```

You'll have to decode it when reading the cookie back.